# Discontinuity and Dirac's Delta Function

Tags: derivatives, dirac-delta, continuity

[image]

Can someone help me understand how he came up with Dirac's function to differentiate that discontinuous periodic function? I am familiar with Dirac's function, but I don't understand where it came from in this case. Thanks

Comment: Each time there is a vertical slope (a Heaviside function) the derivative will be a delta function.

Comment: Note: the Dirac $\delta$ is **not** a function.

Comment: As usual with the Dirac (non-)function, to reach rigorous statements, one should go to integrals, here the fact that for every $s<t$ ($s$ and $t$ not multiples of $T$, to simplify things), $$x(t)=x(s)+\int_s^t\left(-\frac{1}{T}+\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\delta(u-nT)\right)du=-\frac1T(t-s)+\#\{n\in\mathbb Z\mid s<nT<t\}.$$

Comment: Thank you all. It is no ordinary function, but it is classified as a "generalized" function, so you can call it the Dirac delta function. [See page 38 of K. Shin e J.K. Hammond, ”Fundamentals of signal processing for sound and vibration engineers”, Ed.
John Wiley & Sons, 2008.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in the figure can be constructed by the sum of $i(t)=-t/T$ {which is a straight line at -45 degree slope through the origin} and $j(t)=\sum{} h(t-nT)$ {which is a 'staircase' function comprised of the sum of Heaviside step functions} .

The derivative of $i(t)+j(t)$ yields your results.  So the Dirac distribution 'spikes' come from differentiating the Heaviside step functions in $j(t)$  since the derivative of $h(x-a)$ is $\delta(x-a)$ .

Comment: I know that $h(t)$ can be defined also as $\int_{-\infty}^t \delta (x) \  dx$. So this bring yo your last sentence that is $h'(t) = \delta(t)$. I'm wondering how this can be proven. So why the derivative of the __Heaviside step function__ is the __Dirac delta function__ ?